# My code to Create a Pivot works but the First row field does not work

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

I have been trying to create a pivot table in VBA and I partially succeeded even after creating the pivot cache and the pivot table the first rowFeild does not come up but the second rowFeild shows up even though I have numbered them as .position=1 and .position=2. Please can anyone help me as I am new to VBA coding and need help to fix this..

Where I have given the xlRowField to be "Natural Account" I have that column in my data and also the column "Natural Account Description" but still the code skips the "Natural Account" completely in row field and moves to the second not sure why. Also how to put it in a classic Pivot view my code is not working for that as well.

```
Dim PSheet As Worksheet
    Dim DSheet As Worksheet
    Dim PCache As PivotCache
    Dim PTable As PivotTable
    Dim PRange As Range
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim LastCol As Long

    'On Error Resume Next
    Worksheets("TempData").Activate
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Worksheets("PivotTable").Delete
    Sheets.Add before:=ActiveSheet
    ActiveSheet.Name = "PivotTable"
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Set PSheet = Worksheets("PivotTable")
    Set DSheet = Worksheets("TempData")

    'LastRow = DSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Select
    'LastCol = DSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Set PRange = DSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion

    Set PCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange). _
    CreatePivotTable(tabledestination:=PSheet.Cells(2, 2), TableName:="SalesPivotTable")

    Set PTable = PCache.CreatePivotTable(tabledestination:=PSheet.Cells(2, 2), TableName:="SalesPivotTable")

    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("SalesPivotTable").PivotFields("Natural Account")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
        '.InGridDropZones = True
        '.RowAxisLayout xlTabularRow
    End With

    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("SalesPivotTable").PivotFields("Natural Account Description")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 2
    End With

    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("SalesPivotTable").PivotFields("ME")
        .Orientation = xlColumnField
        .Position = 1
    End With

    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("SalesPivotTable").PivotFields("Net Closing Balance")
        .Orientation = xlDataField
        .Position = 2
        .Function = xlSum
    End With

    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("SalesPivotTable").RowAxisLayout xlTabularRow

    'With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("SalesPivotTable")
        '.InGridDropZones = True
        '.RowAxisLayout xlTabularRow
    'End With
```

Comment: It is *rarely* a good idea to just stick `On Error Resume Next` at the top of the procedure and hope for the best. You have two lines in that first `With` block that apply to a pivot table, not a pivot field.

Comment: thanks for your tip, and I commented out the On Error Resume Next then I faced a block where i added the pivot cache 'set PCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange). _
        CreatePivotTable(tabledestination:=PSheet.Cells(2, 2), TableName:="SalesPivotTable")' where it shows me application defined or object defined error. Not able to fix this.... @Rory

Comment: Is the target sheet empty? Is the range for `PRange` correct?

Comment: @Rory the target sheet is empty and PRange is taking the entire data with current region not sure why or what i am missing...

Comment: Try using the address of prange as the source data, in R1C1 format